# log4net doesn't write to the file

Tags: c#, winforms, log4net

I have a Windows Forms Application and I am trying to use log4net for logging to a file.
In my app.config I have:

```xml
<log4net debug="false">
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender,log4net" >
      <param name="File" value="C:\...\LogFile.txt" />
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout,log4net">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%n%n%n%d [%t] %-5p %c  - %m%n%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <priority value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </root>
    <category name="DesktopLogger.Form1">
      <priority value="ALL" />
    </category>
</log4net>
```

And in the code which is behind the main Form I have:

```
public log4net.ILog    Logger  { get; set; }
```

as a property and in the form initialization I have:

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

this.Logger= LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));
```

After that, on a click button event I have:

```
this.Logger.Info("text for the logger");
```

And when I open the file after that - *nothing* is written to it. It's just an empty file.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the layout:

```
<layout type ...>
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
</layout>
```

You can of course make that layout anything you wish, that's just an example.

Comment: @mathinvalidnik, what does that mean exactly?

Comment: I am saying that it doesn't write to the passed file in the :
<param name="File" value="C:\...\LogFile.txt" />

Answer (score 0):

Whatever Michael suggested should work, but then if it still doesnt then may be you can try adding

```
 <level value="INFO" />
```

in your `<root>` tags

```
    <root>
      <priority value="ALL" />
      <level value="INFO" />
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </root>
```

Comment: I added both of your suggestions but it still doesn't write anything to the file.

Comment: Is the log file getting created?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem as you, following the same tutorial. An answer could help others using it in the future. Use this configuration:

```
<configSections>
<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net"/>
</configSections>
<log4net>
  <root>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
  </root>
  <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
    <param name="File" value="log-file.txt" />
    <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
</log4net>
```